# Access 2013 continous forms data entry

Tags: ms-access

I hope I can explain and ask my question well.

My db is quite small composed of customer,product, order,orderdetails, shipment,shipmentdetails

customer and product are simple tables where you just create and populate entries.

Invoice is the main form containing InvoiceID,customerID, dates, invoice numbers.
invoiceDetails contains the invoiceID,productID, quantity (extra info)

shipment contains shipment info (date departed, number, location and some others)
shipmentDetails contains shipmentID,invoiceID,invoiceDetailsID and some other info

I tried to skip the table specific data entry fields as I think these maybe irrelevant and easier to input.

I'm trying to create a subform, continous form for data entry.
In this form, I wanted the user to enter a filter for an invoice number (in a textbox f123 for example) and populate a few textboxes (based on the invoiceID, customerID, query etc) and a combobox(for the invoiceDetails) where you can select an invoiceDetail (which updates a few other textboxes length,width,height) and a qty textbox.

I have actually succeeded in typing a text into a textbox, requery a combobox to display the filtered items, and update some textboxes based on the combobox selection. But this was on a main form.

In the continous form, I managed to do somethings similar, input into textbox, which updated a combobox1, upon selection updates textboxes 2 3 4, combobox2. Upon selecting invoiceDetails from combobox2, it updates textboxes 5 6 7, then allows me to input on the other textboxes. This also saves the data fine in the database.

My problem comes after as this is a continous form. Upon typing the filter into the unbound control (textbox1) the combobox1 is updated. All combobox1s from each row before and after are also affected (visually). The other problem is that, if I go to another row that has already been recorded into the database, I can easily edit the new information and erase old work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmhSj.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQXXR.jpg

I've attached a step by step sample. This is the only way I know how at the moment, but I am looking for a workaround (first combobox is very unnecessary for example).

Sorry for the wall of text

Comment: This is behaviour by design. 1: Unbound controls will display the same value on all records. 2: Moving away from a record will save this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the continuous form .allowedits = false
But you can't have different combo box lists for each record, if I understand what you are saying right